# Internet Explorer Opening Local HTML Files in IE7 Document Mode

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-7

For some reason, no matter what document type I'm using Internet Explorer will open all my HTML files as a Default Internet Explorer 7 Document Type. If I upload these HTML files to a server they'll show up just fine. Is there some kind of setting in Internet Explorer or meta tag I need? Doc Types I've tried, which again work when uploaded to a server but not locally (IE Only)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Here's what my dev tools tells me:

[image]

Comment: Are you on a domain?  Have you checked Compatibility settings for "intranet" zones?

Comment: Under zones I'm just on Internet, not local or anything

Comment: Have you tried resetting IE to defaults?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are displaying local files in Compatibility view. In IE, go to Tools/Compatibility View Settings. Check to ensure that your local server is not in the list of sites to display in Compatibility view. Also, ensure that the "display intranet sites in Compatibility View" checkbox is unchecked.

There is also a way to ensure IE does not display in Compatibility view by using the following vendor specific meta tag in the html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

You can read more about that here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876(v=vs.85).aspx